# How to kill bash fork bomb

Tags: bash, forking

Recently I unintentionally created and run a fork bomb in bash. It was a slow one, in comparison to other fork bombs, I had plenty of time to do something. But there were already several hundreds of *bash* instances when I found out though.

My first thought was to do

```
killall bash
```

but this kills the shell I'm in and the *killall* with it.

Then I ran `:!killall bash` from *Vim* and it was settled.

But what if I had no Vim running? Every terminal I have starts bash by default. How could I kill every bash instance but the one I'm in?

Comment: [What's the best way to clean up after a fork bomb?](//serverfault.com/q/148642)

Comment: [How do I kill a forkbomb process?](//superuser.com/q/168804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured I can do exactly what I'm asking, kill every bash instance but the one I'm in.

```
pgrep bash | grep -v $$ | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 0):

just look for the pid and then -

> while true; do killall -u pid; done